# Поиск цифр в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив `symbols`. После каждого символа идет цифра. Только 1 цифра в массиве неверная, в массиве нужно найти лишнюю цифру, которая не схожа с другими.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.promoCode');

var symbols = input.value.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < symbols.lenght; i++) { symbols[i] }
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить ваши наработки?

Comment: const input = document.querySelector('.promoCode'); 
symbols = input.value;

Comment: Как вы проходитесь по массиву? Покажите пример этого массива

Comment: for (int i < 1; i <= symbols.length; i++) {
symbols[i];
}

Comment: @Павел Вороник Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив пример данных и свой код.

Comment: что значит _цифру, которая не схожа с другими_?

Comment: пример: E1X1A1M1P2L1E1, и 2 есть лишняя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str = 'E1X1A1M1P2L1E1';
const symbols = str.split('');
console.log(uniq(symbols));

function uniq(arr) {
    const store = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      !acc[cur] ? acc[cur] = 1 : acc[cur]++
      return acc
    }, {})
    return Object.keys(store).filter(key => Number.parseInt(key) && store[key] === 1)
  }
```